# Is there a service that creates a pass that supports the express mode of the wallet?

Tags: ios, nfc, wallet, hce, apple-wallet

Thank you for reading.

I'm trying to make a system that turns on the iPhone just by holding it over a certain machine.
To do that, I need to put a pass that supports express mode into the user's iPhone wallet.
It would be ideal to have a system like Japan's SuiCa where after registering an IC card in the iPhone, the ticket gate can be unlocked simply by holding the iPhone over the ticket gate.
There are many services that create passes, but all of them can only create barcode type or normal NFC type passes.
Even making a normal NFC type pass must go through Apple's strict examination and get approval, so I think it's more difficult to get approval for a pass that supports express mode.
Perhaps because of that, only global car manufacturers are able to create passes that support express mode.
Therefore, the service I want may not exist.
However, if you know of a service that can create a pass that supports express mode, please let me know.

Thank you very much.

I searched for a service that creates a pass compatible with the express mode of the wallet, but I couldn't find it.
I hope to find a service that will create a pass for the express mode of the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

NFC Passes can do that to an extent.  You will need to obtain an [NFC Pass Type ID Certificate](http://developer.apple.com/contact/passkit) from Apple and use NFC reader with firmware that implements the Apple VAS protocol or create an app that uses iOS's [NFCVASReaderSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcvasreadersession) class and configure it to poll for your NFC Pass Type ID, to be able to automatically wake the iPhone and select your NFC pass.  Note that the Apple VAS protocol only polls for passes and makes them appear automatically.  It is not possible to engage with the pass automatically like an Express pass, because the user still has to authenticate.  But the experience is slicker than having to manually select a pass.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I actually created an NFC type pass using the pass creation service.
As you said, when the iPhone is brought close to the reader, the sleep is automatically canceled, and when the Face ID / passcode is unlocked, it was confirmed that the NFC type pass can be used.
However, I want to use the pass without unlocking the Face ID/passcode like the express mode pass.
Is it possible for a general developer to create a pass that can be used without unlocking the Face ID/passcode?

Comment: It is possible.  You don't need to do anything with your pass. but the reader needs to be programmed to poll for your NFC Pass Type ID.  Users may have multiple NFC passes in their phone, so it is up to the reader to communicate to the phone which pass it is looking for.  For that, the reader needs to implement the Apple VAS protocol.  This modifies the standard ISO 14443 polling loop to broadcast the NFC Pass Type ID it is looking for and if found, commences the APDU dialogue to retrieve the encrypted  payload.

Comment: The Apple VAS specification is provided by Apple under NDA.  If you already have an NFC certificate, you should be able to get this from the Apple representative that authorised your request.  There are also companies like VTAP that provide out of the box solutions. https://www.vtapnfc.com

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I didn't know that there is a company that provides such products and services.
Thank you for teaching!
With this, if I create an NFC compatible pass, I can operate the machine without unlocking the passcode.
I will contact VTAP as soon as possible.
thank you very much.